# How to get workplace integration permissions?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-workplace

I'm looking for a way to check if the correct integration permission has been ticked on the app settings as well as the Page webhook settings.

Is there a way to get what permissions does an app access token has? Specifically for Workplace custom integration. Just like me/permissions on graph api.

Update:
I got it working as @Prateek said. Using [https://graph.facebook.com/v7.0/community?access_token={accessToken}&fields=install](https://graph.facebook.com/v7.0/community?access_token=%7BaccessToken%7D&fields=install)

I also had the answer on how to get the page webhook events. Using [https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/app/subscriptions?access_token={accessToken}](https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/app/subscriptions?access_token=%7BaccessToken%7D) in this case it needed an app access token instead of page access token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try /community GET API

[https://graph.facebook.com/v7.0/community?access_token={accessToken}&fields=install](https://graph.facebook.com/v7.0/community?access_token=%7BaccessToken%7D&fields=install)

Comment: Thank you Prateek, it works! Is there also a way to check if webhook permissions is ticked? eg. messaging_postbacks and messages